# vuejs import my own javascript file

Tags: javascript, laravel-5, webpack, vue.js

I have a php laravel 5.4 project and I wrote a js class for my client-side stuffs.

I'm a newbie in this world, and some questions come up;

1. How can I import / add my script (`CookiesManager.js`) (nicely way) to my `app.js` file and use inside the `vue.js` environment?
2. Should I make a module, and if yes how can import it?

Now I try with this in `app.js`:

```
import {CookiesManager, cm} from './modules/CookiesManager.js';
```

But I got an error

```
[Vue warn]: Error in created hook: "TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__modules_CookiesManager_js__.CookiesManager is undefined"
```

Thanks the responses in advance.

**UPDATE:**

my `CookiesManager.js` file:

```
function CookiesManager (){
    this.about = {
      Version: 0.1,
      Author: "LakiGeri",
      Created: "2017.05",
      Updated: "-"
    }
    this.getCookie = function (cname) {
        var name = cname + "=";
        var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
        for(var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
            var c = ca[i];
            while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
                c = c.substring(1);
            }
            if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
                return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
            }
        }
        return "";
    }
};
```

**UPDATE2:**

I added the `export` at the beginning.

```
export function CookiesManager (){ .. };
```

Now I got this error:

```
[Vue warn]: Error in created hook: "TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__modules_CookiesManager_js__.a.getCookie is not a function"
```

Comment: Please add the content of CookiesManager.js

Comment: Show the content of CookiesManager.js, namely how you export things.

Comment: You'll probably want to require that from the `assets` folder so it's found by webpack.

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export

Comment: Add `export` before function. Or below your code type `export default { CookiesManager }`. And import as `import {CookiesManager as cm} from './modules/CookiesManager.js';` - notice `as`.

Comment: I tried to add `export { CookiesManager, cm };` end of the CookiesManager.js and I tried to add at the begining: `export function CookiesManager (){ ...`
but I got this error: 
`[Vue warn]: Error in created hook: "TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__modules_CookiesManager_js__.a.getCookie is not a function"`
What is the problem?

Comment: @wostex what is your opinion?

Comment: Try exporting as `export function CookiesManager (){...}` and import as `import {CookiesManager as cm} from './modules/CookiesManager'` - works fine in my test environment.

Comment: Unfortunately It does not want to work.. maybe because of vue.js and laravel stuff. I have to "go deeper". Thx btw @wostex